# Passing in part of a vector to a function in C++

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I have a vector that has a size of 1000. I want to pass in part of that vector into this function:

```
template <typename T>
void insertion_sort (vector<T> &a) { // vector: pg 1012; & (reference): pg 383
  for (long int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) {
    for (long int j = i; (j > 0) && (a[j] < a[j-1]); j--) {
      std::swap(a[j], a[j-1]);  
    }
  }
}
```

Say I want to sort the vector from 100-1000. 
Would I pass into the function like this:

```
insertion_sort(&a[100]);
```

I tried to use an iterator, but the function will not accept it. In this case, I am afraid that when `size()` is called, it will be 1000 instead of 900.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is the wrong way to go about it in C++, you shouldn't accepting a vector but an iterator that represents the ranges in the vector.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify the insertion_sort code above.

Comment: Then you'll have to create a new vector.

Comment: What @chris said if this is "homework code".

Comment: @MorphingDragon Yes sorry insertion_sort is the code I was provided with and I am using it in mergesort. But I am calling insertion_sort many times, if I create a new vector, that would be bad time complexity.

Comment: @Renren29 - The function takes a vector, so you have to pass a vector.  Sorry, but it's that simple.  Unless you use iterators or change the function in some way, it looks like you're stuck.  If the person who gave you this code complains about the time it takes to run your program, just say it's their fault, not yours, that such a stinky interface was given to you.

Comment: @Renren29 iterators are how we do efficient slicing ("Sub Vectors" so to speak) of containers in C++. If this is homework code bring this up with your teacher, it would be a good learning experience.

Comment: It's kind of worth noting that we'll hopefully be seeing `array_view` soon enough instead of only iterators.

Comment: Ok, I will contact my professor about this. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot modify the function provided you can create a copy of vector, pass it to function and copy back:

```
std::vector<int> v( 1000 );
auto it = v.begin();
std::advance( it, 100 );
std::vector<int> tmp( it, v.end() );
insertion_sort( tmp );
std::copy( tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), it );
```

or you can remove first 100 elements, sort your vector and put them back:

```
std::vector<int> v( 1000 );
auto it = v.begin();
std::advance( it, 100 );
std::vector<int> tmp( v.begin(), it );
v.erase( v.begin(), it );
insertion_sort( v );
v.insert( v.begin(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end() );
```

otherwise function as it currently written does not provide a way to sort a vector partially. To support that it should be written as most standard algorithms are - accepting range by 2 iterators:

```
template< class RandomIt >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last );
```